# Flex: cross-domain image loading?

Tags: apache-flex, cross-domain

OK I have an application that loads product images using the < mx:Image /> tag and changing the source. the .SWF is on the http side of the website and the images are on the https side of the site. so at first I was getting this error:

> SecurityError: Error #2122: Security
>   sandbox violation: Loader.content:
>   http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/Masonic.swf
>   cannot access
>   https://www.MYDOMAIN.com/masonic_images/13_red_d2-MAS72479bl_red.jpg.
>   A policy file is required, but the
>   checkPolicyFile flag was not set when
>   this media was loaded. at
>   flash.display::Loader/get content() at
>   SmoothImage/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::contentLoaderInfo_completeEventHandl
>   er()

So after some research I found this article: http://www.damienking.net/tutorial-using-remotely-hosted-images-flex I did what it said and I am now getting this similar error:

> SecurityError: Error #2123: Security
>   sandbox violation: Loader.content:
>   http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/Masonic.swf
>   cannot access
>   https://www.MYDOMAIN.com/masonic_images/12_red_d2-MAS60338bl_red.jpg.
>   No policy files granted access. at
>   flash.display::Loader/get content() at
>   SmoothImage/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::contentLoaderInfo_completeEventHandl
>   er()

Also after I click dismiss to the error box that pops up, the images do load afterwards, but are then set to the size of the actual image not the width and height I set the component to. I have no clue what to make of that.

Any help is appreciated.

THANKS!

Comment: Are you setting the LoaderContext to true before accessing?

Comment: Yes I am doing it like the tutorial said how to, in the image initialize function.

Comment: Also I have other Flash apps that load https images to the http side without issues. I don't really understand why it is an issue now, they are the same domain.

Comment: Well I got it to work using a proxy after reading this article: http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/jsp-proxy-code-for-sourcing-cross-domain-images/?referer=sphere_related_content/

Comment: You should make that an answer and accept it instead of leaving it here in the comments if you got it to work.

Comment: another article on the same issue: cross domain image loading / security sandbox workarounds: [http://www.onegiantmedia.com/as3---load-a-remote-image-from-any-domain-with-no-security-sandbox-errors](http://www.onegiantmedia.com/as3---load-a-remote-image-from-any-domain-with-no-security-sandbox-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using a proxy, via the instructions on this article: http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/jsp-proxy-code-for-sourcing-cross-domain-images/?referer=sphere_related_content/ I think the images load slower and its probably not the ideal solution but at least it works now and thats better than nothing.